# Sun CC: where does symbol "PointZERO" come from? It's not in my source code

Tags: c++, linker, solaris

This is a really weird problem. I'm compiling a C++ project on Solaris 10, with cc "Sun C 5.7 2005/01/07" and Bison 1.25 (if that matters). After finally getting the libs built, it still fails to link the executables, with following error message:

```
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
PointZERO                           /export/build/proj/lib/libMainLib.so
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to bin/the_exe
```

**Does anyone know this "PointZERO" symbol?** It's not in my code; nor is the string contained in any of my libraries. I've never seen this name before. And I haven't found anything about this on Google...

Answer (score 1):

Well, ouch... The error was induced by an #include <...> statement in one of the source files, which (for unknown reasons) was used to include a file from a completely different project.

Very embarrassing for a number of reasons. Lesson: more thorough code reviews before checking in.